# Mock test case get failed unexpectedly

Tags: azure, unit-testing, mocking, azure-pipelines, xunit

When I locally execute my mock test in c# then my test case gets passed but when I queue my build to azure then some of the random test cases fail which was getting passed locally? Any solution on this?

Comment: You should share more info about your question, otherwise, no one will be able to know the reason of this issue. At latest, you should share the failed log.

Comment: @Alex do u think it is because of Threading issue?

Answer (score 0):

I got to know this was getting failed because my mock object was static. Check my another question [Why my few test case get failed after "Running all" controller and pass individually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56865435/why-my-few-test-case-get-failed-after-running-all-controller-and-pass-individu)